# module 'pytesseract' has no attribute 'image_to_string'

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-tesseract

I've been trying to solve this error for a long time. I have googled this error and find nothing to solve it.

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tess.py", line 6, in <module>
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image_file)))
AttributeError: module 'pytesseract' has no attribute 'image_to_string'
```

Please also tell me, What would be the "pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'System_path_to_tesseract'"  for ubuntu

code

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import *
import pytesseract

image_file = '4.jpg'
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image_file)))
```

Help me to solve this error
Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message in the title is different from the one shown in the post. Please edit the question to clarify this. And please reduce this to a [mre].

Comment: Delete `from pytesseract import *` line and compile again.